# Run Drawing SVG When Scroll of window

Tags: css, svg, scroll, drawing

i have svg and i'm put animation using @keyframes for this svg.. and it's working..

but my issue : how to make drawing of this svg when we scroling of window (browser)...

so, when user scroll down, this svg begin drawing....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 <style>
            .oa-hotel {
           fill: #FFF;
              stroke: #FFF;
              stroke-dasharray: 500;
              stroke-dashoffset: 500;
            }
            .oa-hotel-animate {
              -webkit-animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
              animation: dash 5s linear alternate;
            }
            @keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 500; fill: #FFF !important;
                    fill: black;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0; fill: #FFF !important;
                    fill: white;
                }
            } 
            @-webkit-keyframes dash {
                from {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
                    fill: black;
                }
                to {
                    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                    fill: white;
                }
            }               
 </style>
</head>
<body style="background: black;">

<svg id="ps4" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" viewBox="0 0 600 318" enable-background="new 0 0 600 318" xml:space="preserve">

 <path class="oa-hotel oa-hotel-animate" d="M136.1,10.7c0.3,0.7,0.4,0.9,0.5,1.2c4.3,10.2,8.5,20.3,12.8,30.5c3.3,7.9,6.6,15.7,9.9,23.6
 c0.8,1.8,2.6,2.6,4.2,1.7c1.8-0.9,0.8-2.2,0.3-3.4c-5.1-12.3-10.3-24.6-15.5-37c-3.2-7.6-6.4-15.2-9.5-22.8
 c-0.6-1.4-1.4-2.2-3.1-2.1c-1.6,0-2,1-2.5,2.1c-2.1,5-4.2,10-6.3,15c-2.4,5.7-4.8,11.3-7,17c-0.3,0.8-0.3,2,0.1,2.6
 c0.9,1.1,3.9,0.2,4.5-1.2c1.1-2.6,2.2-5.3,3.3-7.9C130.6,23.8,133.2,17.4,136.1,10.7z M35.8,37.3c0.4,9.8,5.3,19.4,15.5,26
 c2.1,1.4,2.9,1.1,3.8-1.3c0.7-1.6-0.5-2.3-1.5-3C41.9,51,38.6,38.7,41.9,26.9C46.3,11.7,62.9,3,78,7.8c2.1,0.7,3,0.2,3.7-2
 c0.7-2-0.8-2.3-2.2-2.7C74.5,1.5,69.3,1.1,64,1.9C48,4.5,35.9,18.7,35.8,37.3z M103.2,35.2C102.8,23.6,98,14.3,88.6,7.5
 c-1.3-0.9-2.2-0.9-3.1,0.5c-1,1.6-0.9,2.7,0.5,3.6c9.9,6.6,14.7,20.1,11.1,31.5c-3.5,11.4-11.2,18.2-22.9,20.3
 c-4.2,0.8-8.4,0.5-12.6-0.7c-1.6-0.4-2.4,0.3-3.1,2.4c-0.5,1.5,0.5,1.8,1.6,2.2c4.1,1.4,8.3,1.7,12.6,1.3
 C90.9,66.8,103.5,51,103.2,35.2z M134.1,50.4c3.9,0,7.9,0,11.8,0c1,0,2,0,2.1-1.4c0.1-1.3-1.8-3.4-3.1-3.4c-8,0-15.9-0.1-23.9,0.1
 c-2.3,0-4.9,0.6-6,2.9c-2.6,5.6-4.9,11.3-7.2,16.9c-0.2,0.5,0.2,1.7,0.7,2c1.6,1,3.5,0.2,4.2-1.5c1.8-4.2,3.7-8.4,5.3-12.7
 c0.8-2.2,2.3-3,4.5-3C126.4,50.5,130.2,50.4,134.1,50.4z M64,1.9"/>
 <!-- TEXT -->
 <path class="oa-hotel" d="M46.2,105.6v1h-4.7v4.1h-1v-9.1h1v4.1H46.2z M46.9,105.6L46.9,105.6l-0.1,1h0.1v4.1h1v-9.1h-1V105.6z M56.8,103.2l-0.7,0.7
 c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.9c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.3,1.4c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.4c-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.6-1.1,0.8
 c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.3-1.4,0.3c-0.5,0-1-0.1-1.4-0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.6l-0.7,0.7c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.2,0.8
 c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.8,0.4c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.8-0.4c0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4-1c0.4-0.4,0.7-0.9,1-1.4c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.4-1.8
 c0-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.4-1.8C57.4,103.9,57.1,103.5,56.8,103.2z M50.2,107.5c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.3-1.4c0-0.5,0.1-1,0.3-1.4
 c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-1.1c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.6,1.1-0.8c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4-0.3c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.3c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.8,0.6l0.7-0.7
 c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.6-1.2-0.8c-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.8-0.4c-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.8,0.4c-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4,1c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.9-1,1.4
 c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.4,1.8c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.4,1.8c0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.8,1.1l0.7-0.7C50.5,108,50.3,107.8,50.2,107.5z M57.7,102.5h2.9
 v0.1h1v-0.1h2.9v-1h-6.8V102.5z M60.6,110.6h1v-7.4h-1V110.6z M65.5,110.6h1v-1h0v-3.1h0v-1h0v-3.1h0v-0.9h0.7v0.9h4.4v-1h-6V110.6z
  M71.5,110.6v-1h-4.4v1H71.5z M70.2,106.6v-1h-3v1H70.2z M73.5,109.7v-8.1h-1v9.1h1.2v-1H73.5z M74.4,110.6h4.2v-1h-4.2V110.6z
  M82.5,109.7c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6l0-0.4h-1l0,0.4v0.1
 c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8s0.6,0.4,0.9,0.5c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1.1,0.2h0.4v-1H82.5z M85.6,106.5
 c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.3h0c0,0-0.2,0-0.7,0v0h-0.4h0h-0.1c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1
 c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5
 c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3s0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1h0.1v-0.9h0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0h-0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.2s-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.5
 c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,0.9,0.5,1.6,1.5,2.2c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1h0.2h0.1h0
 c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.8,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1v1c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8-0.1c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,0.9-0.5
 c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.6-0.8c0.2-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9C85.9,107,85.8,106.7,85.6,106.5z M83.7,102.6
 c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l0,0.3h1l0-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.9
 c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.5c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1v0.9C83.6,102.6,83.7,102.6,83.7,102.6z M105.9,101.6
 v0.9h2.2c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1h-2.2v1.6l3.9,3.5h1.4l-4.6-4.1h1.5
 c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.5c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.2-1
 c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.5c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.2 M104.5,101.5v9.1h0.7v-9.1 M118.2,110.6v-1h-4.4v1
 H118.2z M116.9,106.6v-1h-3v1H116.9z M112.2,110.6h0.9v-9.1h0.7v0.9h4.4v-1h-6V110.6z M124.9,106.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6
 c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.3h0c0,0-0.2,0-0.7,0v0h-0.4h0H122c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
 c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1v-1
 c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7,0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.5c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,0.9,0.5,1.6,1.5,2.2
 c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1h0.2h0.1h0c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.8,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3s0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5
 c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5s-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8,0.1h-0.2v1h0.2
 c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.1-0.2c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,0.9-0.5c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.6-0.8c0.2-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9
 C125.2,107,125.1,106.7,124.9,106.5z M122.4,101.6v0.9c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5
 c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l0,0.3h1l0-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.9c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.5
 C123.1,101.6,122.7,101.5,122.4,101.6 M121.1,109.6c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6
 l0-0.4h-1l0,0.4v0.1c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2v-1
 C121.5,109.7,121.3,109.6,121.1,109.6z M134.3,102.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.7-1.4-1c-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.8-0.4c-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.8,0.4
 c-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4,1c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.9-1,1.4c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.4,1.8c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.4,1.8c0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.7,1.1l0.7-0.7
 c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.8c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.3-1.4c0-0.5,0.1-1,0.3-1.4c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-1.1c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.6,1.1-0.8
 c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4-0.3c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.3c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.5l0.7-0.7l0.5,0.5l-0.6,0.6c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.9
 c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.3,1.4c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.4c-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.6-1.1,0.8c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.3-1.4,0.3
 c-0.5,0-0.9-0.1-1.4-0.3c-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.6l-0.7,0.7c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.2,0.8c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.8,0.4c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.8-0.4
 c0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4-1s0.7-0.9,1-1.4c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.4-1.8c0-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.4-1.8C135,103.8,134.7,103.3,134.3,102.9z
  M138.3,101.6v0.9h1.9c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0.1s0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1h-1.9v1.8l3.6,3.2h1.4l-4.6-4.1h1.5
 c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.5c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.2-1
 c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.5c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.2 M136.6,101.5v9.1h1v-3.9l0.1,0v-1.2h-0.1v-3.1h0.1v-0.9
  M147.2,102.5h2.9v-1h-6.8v1h2.9v0.1L147.2,102.5L147.2,102.5z M146.2,110.6h1v-7.4h-1V110.6z M153.1,109.7c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8-0.1
 c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6l0-0.4h-1l0,0.4v0.1c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1
 c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.5c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1.1,0.2h0.2v-1H153.1z M156.6,107.3c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.8
 c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6s-0.6-0.2-1-0.3h0c0,0-0.2,0-0.7,0v0h-0.4h0h-0.1c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3
 c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3
 c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.1v-0.9h0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0h-0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.2c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.5
 c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,0.9,0.5,1.6,1.5,2.2c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1h0.2h0.1h0
 c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.7,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1v1c0.4,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,0.9-0.5
 c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.6-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1C156.8,107.8,156.7,107.5,156.6,107.3z M154.3,102.6c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3
 c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l0,0.3h1l0-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.9c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8
 c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.5c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1v1C154.1,102.6,154.2,102.6,154.3,102.6z M98.5,105.7h-0.9c0,0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.8
 c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7l-1.6-1.9c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.7-0.6c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5s0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5
 c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.1-0.7c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.1c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7,0.1
 c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.4c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.6
 l0.5,0.6c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8,0.5c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.6,0.6s-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.8c0,0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.8
 c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.7c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1.1,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.2
 c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.4l0.6,0.8h1.3l-1.4-1.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5
 c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6C98.4,106.2,98.4,106,98.5,105.7z M94.9,105.7l1.8,2.3c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3
 c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4
 c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.4C94.6,105.9,94.7,105.8,94.9,105.7z
  M95.2,104.7l-0.4-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.2
 c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.5,0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.4
 c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4C95.7,104.3,95.5,104.5,95.2,104.7z"/>

 <path class="oa-hotel oa-hotel-animate" d="M197.6,87.5c0,0.7-0.6,1.3-1.3,1.3H3.7c-0.7,0-1.3-0.6-1.3-1.3l0,0c0-0.7,0.6-1.3,1.3-1.3h192.6
    C197,86.2,197.6,86.8,197.6,87.5L197.6,87.5z"/>

</svg>

</body>
</html>

shareedit
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this i modified the code i found here http://codepen.io/paintbycode/pen/JDbcF hope this helps.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  
  //set the units for the svg paths
  $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset", "1000");
  $(".path").css("stroke-dasharray", "1000");

  //variable for the 'stroke-dashoffset' unit
  var $dashOffset = $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset");//.star

  //on a scroll event - execute function
  $(window).scroll(function () {    
 
 var top = $(window).scrollTop();
 
    //calculate how far down the page the user is 
    var $percentageComplete = ((top/($("html").height()-$(window).height()))*100);    

    //convert dashoffset pixel value to interger
    var $newUnit = parseInt($dashOffset, 10); 

    //convert percentage complete unit to an interger
//    var $parsedPercentage = parseInt($percentageComplete, 10);

    //get the value to be subtracted from the 'stroke-dashoffset'
    var $offsetUnit = $percentageComplete * ($newUnit / 100);

    //set the new value of the dashoffset to create the drawing effect
    $(".path").css("stroke-dashoffset", $newUnit - $offsetUnit);
 $(".path").css("fill-opacity", 0  + top * .001);
 
 
  });

});
```

```css
body {
 color: white;
 height: 2000px;
}


svg {
  position: fixed;
 
  left: 30%;
  
}


.path {
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Scroll</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>

<body style="background: black;">

<svg id="ps4" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="900px" viewBox="0 0 600 318" enable-background="new 0 0 600 318" xml:space="preserve">


  <g id="Group" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1" fill="none"><!--CHANGE LINE COLOUR-->
    
    
 <path class="path" stroke="#fff" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" d="M136.1,10.7c0.3,0.7,0.4,0.9,0.5,1.2c4.3,10.2,8.5,20.3,12.8,30.5c3.3,7.9,6.6,15.7,9.9,23.6
 c0.8,1.8,2.6,2.6,4.2,1.7c1.8-0.9,0.8-2.2,0.3-3.4c-5.1-12.3-10.3-24.6-15.5-37c-3.2-7.6-6.4-15.2-9.5-22.8
 c-0.6-1.4-1.4-2.2-3.1-2.1c-1.6,0-2,1-2.5,2.1c-2.1,5-4.2,10-6.3,15c-2.4,5.7-4.8,11.3-7,17c-0.3,0.8-0.3,2,0.1,2.6
 c0.9,1.1,3.9,0.2,4.5-1.2c1.1-2.6,2.2-5.3,3.3-7.9C130.6,23.8,133.2,17.4,136.1,10.7z M35.8,37.3c0.4,9.8,5.3,19.4,15.5,26
 c2.1,1.4,2.9,1.1,3.8-1.3c0.7-1.6-0.5-2.3-1.5-3C41.9,51,38.6,38.7,41.9,26.9C46.3,11.7,62.9,3,78,7.8c2.1,0.7,3,0.2,3.7-2
 c0.7-2-0.8-2.3-2.2-2.7C74.5,1.5,69.3,1.1,64,1.9C48,4.5,35.9,18.7,35.8,37.3z M103.2,35.2C102.8,23.6,98,14.3,88.6,7.5
 c-1.3-0.9-2.2-0.9-3.1,0.5c-1,1.6-0.9,2.7,0.5,3.6c9.9,6.6,14.7,20.1,11.1,31.5c-3.5,11.4-11.2,18.2-22.9,20.3
 c-4.2,0.8-8.4,0.5-12.6-0.7c-1.6-0.4-2.4,0.3-3.1,2.4c-0.5,1.5,0.5,1.8,1.6,2.2c4.1,1.4,8.3,1.7,12.6,1.3
 C90.9,66.8,103.5,51,103.2,35.2z M134.1,50.4c3.9,0,7.9,0,11.8,0c1,0,2,0,2.1-1.4c0.1-1.3-1.8-3.4-3.1-3.4c-8,0-15.9-0.1-23.9,0.1
 c-2.3,0-4.9,0.6-6,2.9c-2.6,5.6-4.9,11.3-7.2,16.9c-0.2,0.5,0.2,1.7,0.7,2c1.6,1,3.5,0.2,4.2-1.5c1.8-4.2,3.7-8.4,5.3-12.7
 c0.8-2.2,2.3-3,4.5-3C126.4,50.5,130.2,50.4,134.1,50.4z M64,1.9"/>
 <!-- TEXT -->
 <path stroke="#fff" fill="#fff" stroke-width="0" d="M46.2,105.6v1h-4.7v4.1h-1v-9.1h1v4.1H46.2z M46.9,105.6L46.9,105.6l-0.1,1h0.1v4.1h1v-9.1h-1V105.6z M56.8,103.2l-0.7,0.7
 c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.9c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.3,1.4c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.4c-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.6-1.1,0.8
 c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.3-1.4,0.3c-0.5,0-1-0.1-1.4-0.3c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.6l-0.7,0.7c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.2,0.8
 c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.8,0.4c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.8-0.4c0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4-1c0.4-0.4,0.7-0.9,1-1.4c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.4-1.8
 c0-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.4-1.8C57.4,103.9,57.1,103.5,56.8,103.2z M50.2,107.5c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.3-1.4c0-0.5,0.1-1,0.3-1.4
 c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-1.1c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.6,1.1-0.8c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4-0.3c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.3c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,0.8,0.6l0.7-0.7
 c-0.4-0.3-0.7-0.6-1.2-0.8c-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.8-0.4c-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.8,0.4c-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4,1c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.9-1,1.4
 c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.4,1.8c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.4,1.8c0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.8,1.1l0.7-0.7C50.5,108,50.3,107.8,50.2,107.5z M57.7,102.5h2.9
 v0.1h1v-0.1h2.9v-1h-6.8V102.5z M60.6,110.6h1v-7.4h-1V110.6z M65.5,110.6h1v-1h0v-3.1h0v-1h0v-3.1h0v-0.9h0.7v0.9h4.4v-1h-6V110.6z
  M71.5,110.6v-1h-4.4v1H71.5z M70.2,106.6v-1h-3v1H70.2z M73.5,109.7v-8.1h-1v9.1h1.2v-1H73.5z M74.4,110.6h4.2v-1h-4.2V110.6z
  M82.5,109.7c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6l0-0.4h-1l0,0.4v0.1
 c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8s0.6,0.4,0.9,0.5c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1.1,0.2h0.4v-1H82.5z M85.6,106.5
 c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.3h0c0,0-0.2,0-0.7,0v0h-0.4h0h-0.1c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1
 c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5
 c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3s0.5-0.1,0.8-0.1h0.1v-0.9h0.3c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0h-0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.2s-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.5
 c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,0.9,0.5,1.6,1.5,2.2c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1h0.2h0.1h0
 c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.8,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.1,0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.1v1c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8-0.1c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,0.9-0.5
 c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.6-0.8c0.2-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9C85.9,107,85.8,106.7,85.6,106.5z M83.7,102.6
 c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l0,0.3h1l0-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.9
 c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.5c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5-0.1v0.9C83.6,102.6,83.7,102.6,83.7,102.6z M105.9,101.6
 v0.9h2.2c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1h-2.2v1.6l3.9,3.5h1.4l-4.6-4.1h1.5
 c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.5c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.2-1
 c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.5c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.2 M104.5,101.5v9.1h0.7v-9.1 M118.2,110.6v-1h-4.4v1
 H118.2z M116.9,106.6v-1h-3v1H116.9z M112.2,110.6h0.9v-9.1h0.7v0.9h4.4v-1h-6V110.6z M124.9,106.5c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6
 c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.3h0c0,0-0.2,0-0.7,0v0h-0.4h0H122c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5
 c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3c0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1v-1
 c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7,0.1c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.5c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,0.9,0.5,1.6,1.5,2.2
 c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.7,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1h0.2h0.1h0c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.8,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3s0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5
 c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5s-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.5,0.1-0.8,0.1h-0.2v1h0.2
 c0.4,0,0.8-0.1,1.1-0.2c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,0.9-0.5c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.6-0.8c0.2-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9
 C125.2,107,125.1,106.7,124.9,106.5z M122.4,101.6v0.9c0.2,0,0.5,0,0.7,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5
 c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l0,0.3h1l0-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.9c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.5
 C123.1,101.6,122.7,101.5,122.4,101.6 M121.1,109.6c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6
 l0-0.4h-1l0,0.4v0.1c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1c0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1,0.2v-1
 C121.5,109.7,121.3,109.6,121.1,109.6z M134.3,102.9c-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.7-1.4-1c-0.5-0.2-1.1-0.4-1.8-0.4c-0.6,0-1.2,0.1-1.8,0.4
 c-0.5,0.2-1,0.6-1.4,1c-0.4,0.4-0.7,0.9-1,1.4c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.1-0.4,1.8c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.4,1.8c0.2,0.4,0.5,0.8,0.7,1.1l0.7-0.7
 c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.5-0.5-0.8c-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.3-1.4c0-0.5,0.1-1,0.3-1.4c0.2-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-1.1c0.3-0.3,0.7-0.6,1.1-0.8
 c0.4-0.2,0.9-0.3,1.4-0.3c0.5,0,1,0.1,1.4,0.3c0.3,0.1,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.5l0.7-0.7l0.5,0.5l-0.6,0.6c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.6,0.9
 c0.2,0.4,0.3,0.9,0.3,1.4c0,0.5-0.1,1-0.3,1.4c-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.8,1.1c-0.3,0.3-0.7,0.6-1.1,0.8c-0.4,0.2-0.9,0.3-1.4,0.3
 c-0.5,0-0.9-0.1-1.4-0.3c-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.6l-0.7,0.7c0.4,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.2,0.8c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.4,1.8,0.4c0.6,0,1.2-0.1,1.8-0.4
 c0.5-0.2,1-0.6,1.4-1s0.7-0.9,1-1.4c0.2-0.5,0.4-1.1,0.4-1.8c0-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.4-1.8C135,103.8,134.7,103.3,134.3,102.9z
  M138.3,101.6v0.9h1.9c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.6,0.1s0.4,0.2,0.5,0.3c0.1,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.1,0.4,0.1,0.6c0,0.2,0,0.4-0.1,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.3,0.5c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.3-0.5,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1h-1.9v1.8l3.6,3.2h1.4l-4.6-4.1h1.5
 c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c0.3-0.1,0.6-0.3,0.8-0.5c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.5-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1c0-0.3-0.1-0.7-0.2-1
 c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5-0.8c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.5c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-1-0.2 M136.6,101.5v9.1h1v-3.9l0.1,0v-1.2h-0.1v-3.1h0.1v-0.9
  M147.2,102.5h2.9v-1h-6.8v1h2.9v0.1L147.2,102.5L147.2,102.5z M146.2,110.6h1v-7.4h-1V110.6z M153.1,109.7c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.8-0.1
 c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6l0-0.4h-1l0,0.4v0.1c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1
 c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.6,0.6,0.8c0.3,0.2,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.5c0.4,0.1,0.7,0.2,1.1,0.2h0.2v-1H153.1z M156.6,107.3c-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.5-0.8
 c-0.2-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.8-0.6s-0.6-0.2-1-0.3h0c0,0-0.2,0-0.7,0v0h-0.4h0h-0.1c-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.2-0.6-0.3
 c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.4-0.5c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.4-0.5c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6-0.3
 c0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7-0.1v-0.9h0.5c-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2,0h-0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0.1-1.1,0.2c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.3-0.9,0.5
 c-0.3,0.2-0.5,0.5-0.6,0.8c-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.6-0.2,1c0,0.9,0.5,1.6,1.5,2.2c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.8,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0.1,0.9,0.1h0.2h0.1h0
 c0.3,0,0.5,0,0.7,0.1c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6c0,0.2-0.1,0.4-0.2,0.6
 c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.4,0.5c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.3c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1v1c0.4,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.2c0.4-0.1,0.7-0.3,0.9-0.5
 c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.5,0.6-0.8c0.1-0.3,0.2-0.6,0.2-1C156.8,107.8,156.7,107.5,156.6,107.3z M154.3,102.6c0.2,0.1,0.4,0.2,0.6,0.3
 c0.2,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.2,0.6l0,0.3h1l0-0.4c0-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.3-0.9c-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.5-0.6-0.8
 c-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4-0.9-0.5c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.7-0.1v1C154.1,102.6,154.2,102.6,154.3,102.6z M98.5,105.7h-0.9c0,0.3,0,0.5-0.1,0.8
 c-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.5-0.2,0.7l-1.6-1.9c0.3-0.2,0.5-0.4,0.7-0.6c0.2-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.2-0.5s0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5
 c0-0.2,0-0.5-0.1-0.7c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.4c-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.9-0.1c-0.3,0-0.5,0-0.7,0.1
 c-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.2-0.6,0.4c-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.6c-0.1,0.2-0.1,0.5-0.1,0.7c0,0.2,0.1,0.5,0.2,0.7c0.1,0.2,0.2,0.4,0.4,0.6
 l0.5,0.6c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.3-0.8,0.5c-0.2,0.2-0.5,0.4-0.6,0.6s-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.7c-0.1,0.2-0.2,0.5-0.2,0.8c0,0.3,0,0.5,0.1,0.8
 c0.1,0.3,0.2,0.5,0.5,0.7c0.2,0.2,0.5,0.4,0.8,0.5c0.3,0.1,0.7,0.2,1.1,0.2c0.3,0,0.6,0,0.8-0.1c0.2-0.1,0.4-0.1,0.6-0.2
 c0.2-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.5-0.3c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.2,0.4-0.4l0.6,0.8h1.3l-1.4-1.5c0.1-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.2-0.5
 c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.4,0.1-0.6C98.4,106.2,98.4,106,98.5,105.7z M94.9,105.7l1.8,2.3c-0.1,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.4,0.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4,0.3
 c-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.2c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.6,0.1c-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1c-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.4-0.3c-0.1-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.4
 c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.6c0-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.2-0.3,0.3-0.5c0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.5-0.4C94.6,105.9,94.7,105.8,94.9,105.7z
  M95.2,104.7l-0.4-0.5c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.4-0.1-0.5c0-0.3,0.1-0.5,0.3-0.7c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.7-0.2
 c0.2,0,0.4,0,0.5,0.1c0.1,0,0.2,0.1,0.3,0.2c0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.4c0,0.1,0,0.2,0,0.3c0,0.1,0,0.2-0.1,0.4
 c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.3,0.4C95.7,104.3,95.5,104.5,95.2,104.7z"/>

 <path class="path" fill="#fff" fill-opacity="0" d="M197.6,87.5c0,0.7-0.6,1.3-1.3,1.3H3.7c-0.7,0-1.3-0.6-1.3-1.3l0,0c0-0.7,0.6-1.3,1.3-1.3h192.6
    C197,86.2,197.6,86.8,197.6,87.5L197.6,87.5z"/>
  </g>
</svg>

</body>
```